# Why std::fetch_add returns the old value?

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic, language-design, stdatomic

What are the design purposes or technical restrictions that make the return value of `std::fetch_add` is the one before changed?

Comment: I think it has more to do with the name. the ordering of `fetch_add` suggests to me that it fetches, then adds.

Comment: On x86, `lock xadd` returns the old value. `addAndGet()` in Java is implemented as `getAndAdd() + delta`.

Comment: Maybe for consistency with `fetch_or`, `fetch_and` where returning the old value is an essential feature, as it can't be recovered from the new value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a big deal either way, you can emulate one in terms of the other.  e.g. `val.add_fetch(1)` can be implemented with `1 + val.fetch_add(1)` if you want it.  However, [GNU C `__atomic` builtins provide both](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html).

Possible reason for ISO C/C++ only providing `fetch_add` instead of `add_fetch`: it makes it cheaper to implement on x86 in some cases; [`lock xadd [mem], reg`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/xadd) leaves reg = old value of mem, mem = sum.  Providing that primitive instead of the other encourages people to design algorithms around that building block, maybe avoiding the need for an extra `add` instruction.

Most RISC ISAs with LL/SC atomics have 3-operand instructions, so they could `add dst, src1, src2` and leave the value from memory undisturbed in another register if code wants it later.  (LL/SC `fetch_add(x)` would normally be implemented as `load-linked reg1, [mem]` / `add reg2, reg1, x` / `store-conditional reg3, reg2, [mem]`.  With a retry loop based on the success/fail result in reg3.  If the `fetch_add` return value is unused, the `add` can overwrite `reg1` instead of using a new reg.

So on most RISCs it's fine either way, and x86 is one of the more-relevant ISAs to care about efficiency on.

---

For some use-cases, `fetch_add` is also what you want.  e.g. for threads grabbing buckets in an array-based circular buffer lock-free queue, with `std::atomic<unsigned> write_idx;` zero-initialized to start with, you want `.fetch_add` to start with `0`.

```
  static std::atomic<unsigned> write_idx = 0;  // shared var

  // in each thread:
  unsigned my_buf = write_idx.fetch_add(1) & ((1<<size) - 1);
```

You'll get values starting with `0` instead of `1`.  This seems like a plausible pattern for lots of use-cases.

Comment: The other way around is also [available](https://godbolt.org/z/sKfEKz), as `+=`, but you can't adjust the `memory_order` argument, of course. Not that it that last part matters on x86. Not sure if that played any part in the decision.

Comment: @ALX23z: thanks for the attempt to add an example, but I hope the exact form of your example isn't something that you find often; dividing up `y` ranges between threads is much more efficient than having each thread just try to grab a `y` value for itself 1 at a time.  Or was each `x` supposed to already be an index to a bundle of work, and this is "dynamic scheduling" that needs to account for one work unit being slower than another?  Still, it seemed overly simplistic.  Your starting-at-zero point was good, but I used a different example.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, this was for time-uneven jobs. If such jobs are too small ones then one can grab them by bunches, say 128 each time  or more or less depending on work-time expectation.

Comment: Ain't there sth. like LOCK XADD on any RISC-CPU ?

Comment: @EdisonvonMyosotis: AArch64 ARMv8.1 LSE has single-instruction atomic RMWs, as an alternative to LL/SC retry loops.  See https://www.anandtech.com/show/15578/cloud-clash-amazon-graviton2-arm-against-intel-and-amd/2 for some microbenchmarks in high-contention cases (bad for LL/SC retry loops using `ldaex` / `stlex`) vs. single-instruction CAS.  Also https://www.anandtech.com/show/16315/the-ampere-altra-review/3 mentions this.  Any machine can do `fetch_add` or `add_fetch` with an LL/SC retry loop, but only some like AArch64 have single-instruction atomics.